# dismiss LoadingController in Ionic3

Tags: ionic3

I found this code from https://www.techiediaries.com/ionic2/how-to-display-a-loading-indicator-spinner-in-ionic2-apps-using-loading-controller/

If i understand it correctly, it basically dismiss the loading spinner when it receives the email and password

But i don't understand how it works and would want to know how it works.

I tried to find other tutorials on LoadingController but they are mostly timer based and the Ionic documentation is also timer based which i do not want because the loading is not always the same exact timing, 1000ms for example.

```
constructor(public loadingController:LoadingController){...}

    let loading = this.loadingController.create({content : "Logging in ,please wait..."});
    loading.present();
    this.auth.login('basic', {'email':this.email, 'password':this.password}).then(()=>{
        loading.dismissAll();
    });
```

I don't understand what is

```
... 
auth.login('basic', {'email':this.email, 'password':this.password}) 
...
```

Comment: That's just a call to an async method that returns a promise... The `.then(() => { ... })` is executed when the method finishes, so that you know that you can hide the loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieve using **promise**

> ***Reference*** https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/promise.html
>
> **Promise** The Promise class is something that exists in many modern JavaScript engines and can be easily polyfilled. The main motivation
> for promises is to bring synchronous style error handling to Async /
> Callback style code.

```
 this.Profile.registration().then((data) => {
      console.log('data arrived the data', data);
      //Dismisisng the loading 
       loading.dismiss();
}
```